# Mathematical explanation for this relationship

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I have analyzed some data, and noticed that it fits this relationship quite well:

$$P(A|B\cap C) = P(A|B)\frac{P(A|C)}{P(A)}$$

I am wondering what the interpretation of this would be mathematically, e.g. what kind of assumptions about independence or other things you would need to go from the left to right hand side. A priori, I believe events $B$ and $C$ to be independent, so the relationship would reduce to:

$$
\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(B)P(C)} = \frac{P(A\cap B)P(A\cap C)}{P(A)P(B)P(C)}\\
P(A\cap B\cap C) = \frac{P(A\cap B)P(A\cap C)}{P(A)}\\
$$

However, I can't find a way to take it further than that. Are there other standard statistical identities/properties that help explain this relationship, or is this just its own unique occurrence that doesn't have further explanation?

**Edit:** Added $P(A)$ on bottom of right hand side

Comment: Is it possible you're mixing up $\cup$ and $\cap$?

Comment: You're right, I did mix those up. I switched them to $\cap$ now

Comment: To answer this, we will need to clear up some things. 1) "$P(A)$ is independent of $P(B)$" does not make sense. I think you mean the events $A$ and $B$ are independent, meaning $P(A,B) = P(A)P(B)$. Is that what you mean? 2) How are the events $A$, $B$, and $C$ related to the total sample space? Does $P(A \cup B \cup C) = 1$?

Comment: 1) Yes that was what I meant 2) So maybe it would help if I fill in a simplified description for the events, and then you can say whether or not I erred in converting it to formal equation. $A$: drawing a red ball from a bag; $B$: the type/fabric of bag I chose at beginning of month prior to any drawing event; $C$: the day that I drew from the bag. The bag's distribution (red vs blue) changes each day, and that distribution is somehow related to the type/fabric of the bag.